# $(\mathbb{Q}\times\mathbb{R})\cup (\mathbb{R}\times\{0\})$ is path-connected but not localy connected

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

I have to prove that $A=(\mathbb{Q}\times\mathbb{R})\cup (\mathbb{R}\times\{0\})$

is path-connected, one in the chat suggested to take $$\varphi(t)=\begin{cases} (x,(1-3t)y), t\in [0,\frac13]\\ ((2-3t)x+(3t-1)x',0), t\in [\frac13,\frac23]\\ (x',(2t-2)y'), t\in [\frac23,1]\end{cases}$$ where $(x,y),(x',y')$ are two points from $A$.

Is it sufficient to defined this continuous application to say that $A$ is path connected? can we for example defined $\varphi$ on $[0,\frac12]\cup [\frac12,1]$ ?

And how can i prove that $A$ is not localy connected, how to find a point from $A$ which has no local base of connected neighborhoods ?

Thank you.

Comment: Every point of $A$ has a connected nbhd, namely, $A$ itself. However, every $\langle q,r\rangle\in A$ with $q\ne 0$ has an open nbhd that does not *contain* any connected open nbhd of $\langle q,r\rangle$, which means that $A$ is not locally connected at $\langle q,r\rangle$.

Comment: what is $<q,r>$ ? i don't understand you say every point of $A$ has a connected neignborhood after that you say that is not locally connected ?

Comment: $\langle q,r\rangle$ is the ordered pair whose first component is $q$ and whose second component is $r$; another, more common notation for it is $(q,r)$. Yes, $A$ is connected, so it’s a connected nbhd of every one of its points. Your problem is that you’ve misunderstood the definition of local connectedness. ‘$X$ is locally connected’ does *not* mean simply that every point of $X$ has a connected nbhd: it means that every point of $X$ has a local base of connected nbhds. The only points of $A$ for which that’s true are the points on the $x$-axis.

Comment: ok i edited my question so the point are $(x,0)$ a neighborhood of $(x,0)$ is $(]x-\varepsilon,x+\varepsilon[\cap Q)\times ]-\varepsilon, \varepsilon[$ right ?

Comment: No, but $\langle x,0\rangle$ has a base of open nbhds of the form $$\big((x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon)\times(-\epsilon,\epsilon)\big)\cap A\;.$$ However, these are the points where $A$ **is** locally compact; to show that $A$ is not locally compact, you want to consider points **not** on the $x$-axis.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: locally s/compact/connected/

Comment: why $\big((x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon)\times(-\epsilon,\epsilon)\big)\cap A\;$ is connected please ?

Comment: because it is path-connected?

Comment: @Alex: Thanks; my fingers sometimes override my brain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To "see" the path-connectedness, just notice that $A$ includes all the "vertical lines" ($Q \times R$) and one "horizontal line" ($R \times \{0\}$).

So any two points $(q_1,r_1)$ and $(q_2,r_2)$ are connected by the following continuous path:

- first the "vertical segment" $(q_1,r_1) - (q_1,0)$
- second the "horizontal segment" $(q_1,0) - (q_2,0)$
- last the "vertical segment" $(q_2,0) - (q_2,r_2)$

That is basically what your function $\varphi$ does, but the geometric description may make it clearer to you.

The case when the second point (or both first and second) is of type $(r,0)$ is simple.

To show that $A$ is not locally-connected, you need to show that there exists a point $x$ with an open set $V$ st $x \in V \subset A$ and $V$ is not connected, i.e. you can divide $V$ into two disjoint open sets: $X,Y$ open, $V = X \cup Y$ and $X \cap Y = \{\}$.

Advice:

- understand your topology (here the topology induced by $R^2$ on $A$), which will give you a description of your open sets (this is why the sets $(]q-e,q+e[ \times ]r-e,r+e[) \cap A$ are a basis of nbhds of $(q,r)$ in $A$) - don't overlook that in general topology exercises (!)
- visualize your set (here a "collection of disconnected vertical lines" plus a "horizontal line")
- check (and understand) your definitions of (i) connected, (ii) locally connected and (iii) path-connected
- remember that (path-connected) $\implies$ (connected) (but not the other way)
- then, consider a point $(q,r)$ "far enough" from the $(R \times \{0\})$ line) and how you can write $]0,2[_{\mathbb Q} = ]0,\sqrt2[_{\mathbb Q} \cup ]\sqrt2,2[_{\mathbb Q}$.

Comment: why we must take it from $\mathbb{R}\times\{0\}$ ?

Comment: because these are the points within $A$ at which ("around which") $A$ is not locally connected (your question). As @BrianMScott hinted, $A$ is locally connected at the points on $R \times \{0\}$. Hint: around points on this horizontal line, you can reproduce the "3-segment" trick in my answer.

Comment: why $A$ is localy connected at the point of $\mathbb{R}\times \{0\}$ ?

Comment: @Vrouvrou: Because the open nbhd that I mentioned in my comment under your question is path-connected and therefore connected. It’s path-connected for the same reason that $A$ is, a reason that Alex has described very clearly.

Comment: So i must take a point (q,r) with $q\in \mathbb{Q}$ and $r\neq 0$ a neighborhood of it is $]q-\varepsilon,q+\varepsilon[\cap Q\times ]r-\varepsilon, r+\varepsilon[$

Comment: this looks correct

Comment: so i must write this neighborhood like $U\cup V$ where $U,V$ are open in this neighborhood disjoint

Comment: can we say that $U=]q-\varepsilon,q[\cap \mathbb{Q}\times ]r-\varepsilon,r+\varepsilon[$ ? or it has no sense i devided q ...

Comment: that's the general idea

Comment: how it can be true there is no q now ?@AlexHalm

Comment: @BrianM.Scott why we can $]q-\varepsilon,q+\varepsilon[\cap Q\times ]r-\varepsilon, r+\varepsilon[=(]q-\varepsilon,q[\cap \mathbb{Q}\times ]r-\varepsilon,r+\varepsilon[)\cup (]q,q+\varepsilon[\cap \mathbb{Q}\times ]r-\varepsilon,r+\varepsilon[)$ ? thank you

Comment: @Vrouvrou: That’s not true, even if $\epsilon\le|q|$: the left-hand side also includes $\{q\}\times(r-\epsilon,r+\epsilon)$.

Comment: so how can you write the neighborhood of (q,r) on $ U \cup V$

Comment: @Vrouvrou: hint: $(]0,\sqrt2[ \cup ]\sqrt2,2[) \cap \mathbb Q$

Comment: we must devide an irrational number ! but how can i express this ?$]q-\varepsilon,q+\varepsilon[\cap Q\times ]r-\varepsilon, r+\varepsilon[=(]q-\varepsilon,k[\cap \mathbb{Q}\times ]r-\varepsilon,r+\varepsilon[)\cup (]k,q+\varepsilon[\cap \mathbb{Q}\times ]r-\varepsilon,r+\varepsilon[)$ where $k \in C_{\mathbb{R}}Q$ and $k\in ]q-\varepsilon,q+\varepsilon[$ we can do this because in the end $k\notin ]q-\varepsilon,q+\varepsilon[\cap \mathbb{Q}$ right ?

Comment: @AlexHalm ?????

Comment: looks right. Now that you know the endgame and the path, you should probably wrap it up on your side to be sure you got all the details and concepts right