# $\mathbb{I}\times\mathbb{Q}\cup\mathbb{Q}\times\mathbb{I}$ and connectedness

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

Is $\mathbb{I}\times\mathbb{Q}\cup\mathbb{Q}\times\mathbb{I}$ connected, where $\mathbb{I}$ is the set of irrational numbers and $\mathbb{I}\times\mathbb{Q}\cup\mathbb{Q}\times\mathbb{I}$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$ with the topology induced by the Pythagorean metric?

Comment: This is a subset of the problem answered here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1202260/mathbbq-times-mathbbr-cup-mathbbr-times-0-is-path-connected-but?rq=1

Comment: It's not connected. $(-\infty,\pi)\times\Bbb R$ and $(\pi,\infty)\times\Bbb R$ are open sets covering it.

Comment: @stefan I believe you have failed to cover the point $\langle\pi, 3\rangle$, which is an element of $\Bbb I\times \Bbb Q$.

Comment: @MJD: What does $\mathbb I$ mean to you? I took it to mean $[0,1]$.

Comment: @MJD: $\pi$ is not in $\mathbb I$.

Comment: I keep thinking $\Bbb I$ means $\Bbb R\setminus \Bbb Q$ for some reason. Thanks.

Comment: @MJD: Ah, that would actually make it a more interesting question. Quique, which is right?

Comment: @MJD: Well, I assume $\Bbb I$ means $I=[0,1]$, but only the OP can answer this.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. I've just edited my question in order to be clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $\mathbb I$ means the set of irrational numbers, then your set is contained in a disjoint union of two open sets in $\mathbb R^2$:
$$ \{ \langle x,y\rangle \mid x+y>0 \} \cup
\{ \langle x,y\rangle \mid x+y<0 \} $$

Answer (score -2):

Try drawing a picture. The topological space you have is a subset of the square $I\times I$, which we can visualize as a subset of the Cartesian coordinate plane. The space $I\times\mathbb Q$ looks like a collection of horizontal lines placed at rational height above the $x$-axis; the space $\mathbb Q\times I$ looks like a collection of vertical lines placed at rational distance from the $y$-axis. The vertical and horizontal lines intersect each other. Do you now see whether the space is connected?